# Auto-generate label and index for description environment

Tags: indexing, description

```
\begin{description}
\item [\textsc{abandon}\label{abandon}\index{abandon}] \textit{verb} desert, leave behind
\end{description
```

Is it possible to automate the above process in such a way that the label and index entry for the description item will be automatically generated.

Comment: Are your index entries just one word? Or do you refer to sub entries as well? `\label` isn't really useful here, since `description` does not use a counter!

Comment: @Christian Yes, my index entries are one word. If description does not use a counter, how can I reference to other words. (E.g. while discussing a certain word, I want reader to able to jump to a description of another word.)

Comment: IMHO, you can refer to myname by writing myname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ? ( a preliminary version only)

Since `description` does not use a counter, the `\label` item is effectively useless, unless a fake counter is introduced.

Since `\item[...]` is applied, I can't use `\xapptocmd` without much efforts, so I put `\refstepcounter{...}` before `\item`, but this is not really nice. I'll try to improve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{xpatch}



\newcounter{itemcntr}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{%
  \setcounter{itemcntr}{0}%
  \xpretocmd{\item}{\refstepcounter{itemcntr}}{}{}%
}
\makeindex



\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
  \textsc{#1}%
  \label{#1}%
  \index{#1}%
}
\begin{document}


\begin{description}
\item [\descitem{abandon}] \textit{verb} desert, leave behind
\item [\descitem{upvote}] \textit{verb} appreciate answers on TeX.SX! 
\end{description}



\clearpage

The term \nameref{upvote} is very important ;-)

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: refname, really does nothing here.

Comment: @touhami: I don't understand. refname? Do you mean `\nameref`?

Comment: yes that is, but don't take it very serious.